# How to get the Excel Cell value by address (A1, A2) using NPOI

Tags: c#, npoi

I have an Excel Cell Address like A1, A2. How do I access this cell programmatically using NPOI framework in C#?

Some Java POI example code I found:

```
CellReference cr = new CellReference("A1"); 
row = mySheet.getRow(cr.getRow()); 
cell = row.getCell(cr.getCol());
```

Comment: I was waited a lot to get a optimal solution from the senior developers,none of them try to help me.So I tried to find a solution my self..Thanks for the valuable support community.

Comment: CellReference cr = new CellReference(cell);
row=cr.Row
col=cr.Col

Answer (score 10):

The Java code you found translates 1:1 into C#:

- First you convert the cell description (A1) into a `CellReference`
- Use the `Row` and `Col` from that CellReference to lookup the actual cell.

Here is some sample code

```
var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
var sheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);

var cr = new CellReference("D5");
var row = sheet.GetRow(cr.Row);
var cell = row.GetCell(cr.Col);

Console.Write(cell.StringCellValue);
```

Do note that referencing an *empty* Cell will result in an exception. Excel doesn't store non-used cells internally, and (N)POI does not attempt to hide that fact from the developer.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful - although it would be even more helpful with datatypes instead of var.

Comment: Don't forget to add all those `using` statements like `using NPOI.SS.Util;` for CellReference, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Here is some sample code that help you get any value.

```
var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
var sheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);

var cr = new CellReference("D5");
var row = sheet.GetRow(cr.Row);
var cell = row.GetCell(cr.Col);

var val = getCellValue(cell);

private object getCellValue(ICell cell)
{
    object cValue = string.Empty;
    switch (cell.CellType)
    {
        case (CellType.Unknown | CellType.Formula | CellType.Blank):
            cValue = cell.ToString();
            break;
        case CellType.Numeric:
            cValue = cell.NumericCellValue;
            break;
        case CellType.String:
            cValue = cell.StringCellValue;
            break;
        case CellType.Boolean:
            cValue = cell.BooleanCellValue;
            break;
        case CellType.Error:
            cValue = cell.ErrorCellValue;
            break;
        default:
            cValue = string.Empty;
            break;
    }
    return cValue;
}
```