# How to get excel cell value by using column name in c# using NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, cell, npoi

I have below condition in my code where the cell value is getting by using Column number.

But I would like to assign values to cells based on column names, as the values I am assigning from an array, the column names in the array are not in the same order as column headers in Excel sheet.

```
if (row.GetCell(columnNumber) != null)
      ICell cell = row.GetCell(columnNumber);
```

Can anyone please let me know how can i get the cell values by using **Column Names**

Answer (score 2):

In my case I needed the column names (in the first row of the xls file) to be used to update a database table. With the hint from @stevenh I did this:

```
                System.Collections.IEnumerator rows = sheet.GetRowEnumerator();

                rows.MoveNext();
                IRow r = (HSSFRow)rows.Current;
                int z = r.LastCellNum - 1;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                for (int j = 0; j < z; j++)
                {
                    ICell cell = r.GetCell(j);
                    dt.Columns.Add(cell.StringCellValue);                    
                }

                rows.Reset();
                while (rows.MoveNext())
                {
                //... get the rest of the data....
```

Which was straightforward enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is a month old, I also ran into the issue of converting a column name to column position (and vice-versa) in NPOI.

Found the answer in this post: [How to get the Excel Cell value by address (A1, A2) using NPOI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608477/how-to-get-the-excel-cell-value-by-address-a1-a2-using-npoi) using NPOI.SS.Util.CellReference.

CellReference allows you to convert in both directions. You can pass in a string cell reference (e.g., "AA1") to get a position, or a row and column to get the string (in CellRefParts array).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to trash NPOI and use EPPlus instead. I wasted 3 days to automate some excel creation with NPOI just to discover that to ADD A COLUMN I have to shift every cell manually and manage empty cell on which NPOI returns null objects.

In EPPlus it woule be simple as that

```
worksheet.Cells["columnname"]
```

Comment: EPPlus is superior - but it does not handle *.xls files. Some of us are forced to work with archaic .xls files and are required to use NPOI.

Comment: @bagofmilk Either you convince the customer to use a free alternative (openoffice, libreoffice, WPS office etc) or, for a really small fee use any of the third party commercial libraries, which does all the boring stuff for you. Compared to the learning curve, absent documentation and time wasted on NPOI, you'll cover the price of that in a matter of day, with the great benefit of being able to use it forever.

Comment: yes but my current issue is with programs - specifically AutoCAD Electrical 2019. The most current version of a major CAD software developer provides data in *.xls and I don't have the authority to let them know the rest of the word has moved on from 2003.

Comment: @bagofmilk try to check if any of the xls third party library does the work for you. I remember being able to work out a solution with the trial version of one of them, which was giving free use in commercial projects, but had a limit on how much rows and sheets you could read/export. Or buy one.

Or, good luck studying NPOI which has so far the worst documentation I've ever seen and lives solely on the skin of the poor bastards who had to put up examples from trial and error. Also, I forgot, if they have installed Microsoft office point straight to Microsoft.Interop API

Comment: @Dave Maybe if you provide your code instead of a generic error report?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Read the header row and persist data in a dictionary of header name (key) and its index (value).
2. Get (or TryGet) value from the dictionary.

The code would look like:

```cs
Dictionary<string, int> indices = 
    headersRow.Cells
              .Select(x => new { x.StringCellValue, x.ColumnIndex })
              .ToDictionary(x => x.StringCellValue, x => x.ColumnIndex);

for (var rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= sheet.LastRowNum; rowIndex++)
{
    var row = sheet.GetRow(rowIndex);

    var hasSuchHeader = indices.TryGetValue(name, out int cellIndex);
    if (hasSuchHeader)
    {
        var cell = row.GetCell(cellIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit of a broad question without being able to see examples of the data you are working with or how you would like the end result but here are some ideas to get you started:

You could have separate designations for each column and sort your data by those columns in a particular order that retains integrity across the sheet. This could be achieved by reading the first row and assigning each column to a variable perhaps.

or

You could possibly note which columns contain what information and order your information in a data structure auch as a binary search tree or hash to organize the data and preserve its structure.